# Bootstrap Modal is not opening in IE11 but opening in Chrome and Egde correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

BootStrap Modal is not opening in IE11 even am not using Fade class and also had meta tag in Master page

Please help with any input as Chrome and Edge is working perfectly with Modal .

Comment: It would be very helpful if you include the actual code that is failing, rather than expecting us to guess what you might have written. Please help us to help you.

Comment: I cant share the code as it is project related to company. anyways will give a highlight that i am reading XM and transforming to XSLT in aspx page. which is having JQUERY and BOOTSTRAP MODAL and everything works fine in Chrome and Edge . However IE11 is not responding to Modal Dialog hence it is not opening or popping up in click unlike other browsers.